# Filter trace output for each CPU

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

My ETM trace is captured separately and loaded with TRACE32 command LA.IMPORT (It is not connected directly with a device)

- How to filter all the records for each core means run 0,1,2 ... from ETB dump in separate windows for LA method?
- Is there method which provides trace data same like capturing from device ?

I tried using `Trace.Find ,core 0` but it is not working. It prints the record number but when I try using `print trace.record.data(recno)` (recno here is which is output of `Trace.Find ,core 0`) I didn't get any record data

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the below commands to check trace data records for core n after importing etb dump . Please comment if it worked or not.

```
la.list /core n
```

or

```
trace.list /core n
```

I could not get the 2nd question. 
The ETB dump is as good as the trace obtained through  live capturing from device. Only difference is that the etb data is stored in DDR or other location, and in live capturing it will be saved in t32 device memory and they will be saved with timestamps if cycle accurate tracing is enabled. If there are no fifo overflows, both will be identical. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for above details , already tried above commands after looking into lauterbach tutorials but it is not working

Comment: Thanks Amal , earlier issue is in trace and these commands are working well